# Unable to use bmatrix

Tags: support, mathjax

I can create a matrix in parentheses:

$$\pmatrix{5 & 6 \\ 5 & 6}$$

but not in square brackets

I can create a matrix in parentheses:

$$\bmatrix{5 & 6 \\ 5 & 6}$$

Why is `\bmatrix` missing on StackExchange?

Answer (score 10):

`$$\begin{bmatrix}5 & 6 \\ 5 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$`

$$\begin{bmatrix}5 & 6 \\ 5 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$

Basically, you have to do it the Latex way, not the Plain Tex way.

Comment: It's inconsistent that the syntax works with pmatrix and not with bmatrix

Comment: The Latex way works with pmatrix also.  So the bug is that naked \pmatrix works at all!

Comment: `\pmatrix` is defined in Plain TeX, but `\bmatrix` is not, and it is not part of the `AMSmath` package on which MathJax is based.  You can, of course use `\def\bmatrix#1{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}` to define it if you want.